# Problem with browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I want to automatically download a .ics file (a calendar file) from a website using selenium with python. The goal is to disable the pop-up window that firefox open when you download a file. To do this, I use the following code :

```
#I set my preferences
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)#not using default folder for downloading
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)#dont show downloading process
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'C:/Users/UserName/Documents/rpi/some folder')#set the directory for download
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'text/calendar')#tell it to automaticaly download a file

#using the profile to access firefox
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='geckodriver',firefox_profile=profile)
```

I first thought that it was a MIME type problem in the line browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk, but after changing the MIME type it's still not working.
From here I have no idea of what is going wrong because my MIME type seems right according to all internet resources I have been able to find.
Perhaps it is a problem of settings or something I haven't noticed...
Anyway thank you for reading this, ask me if you need a bit more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did find a solution by avoiding the problem : i created a new firefox profile > launched firefox with this profile (all of this is done in about:profiles) > went to the web site from wich I wanted to download the file > downloaded the file and checked the "always do this with this type of file" box > launch my programm with this custom profile using the line :

```
profile= webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:/Users/user/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/bqpa3bzv.nameofprofile")
```

This seems to work fine and might be an efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from what I understand, downloading the file prompts a alert box asking if you want to download it, have you tried,

browser.switchtoalert.accept?

Sorry i write in VBA, but you should get the idea,

Thanks

Comment: It's exactly that, I'll try this and validate your answer if it works. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It seems like this solution dont work but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well done for figuring it out, I know the
.switchtoalert.accept works in chromedriver

Let me know if you want any help with anything

Comment: Thank you, it seems like this is solved as my solution worked on all my last test so I close the question.